# Collect strings from css files and persist them into new css file

Tags: ant

I have a process of concatenation several css files into single one.

css1.css:

```
@namespace xlink "http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink";
use[xlink|href="#favorite-icon-svg"] {
  fill:#dbdbdb;
  fill-opacity:0;
}
```

css2.css:

```
body {
  background-color: red;
}
```

css3.css:

```
@namespace svg url(http://www.w3.org/2000/svg);
svg|a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

need to be converted into all.css:

```
@namespace xlink "http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink";
@namespace svg url(http://www.w3.org/2000/svg);

use[xlink|href="#favorite-icon-svg"] {
  fill:#dbdbdb;
  fill-opacity:0;
}
body {
  background-color: red;
}
svg|a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

Some of those css files may contain @namespace directive which needs to be placed at the top of the css file where it is used. Problem is that concatenation makes some @namespace directives placed in the middle of the new file which brokes their functionality.

The task can be divided into two steps:

1. collect all occurencies of @namespace directives and put it into
   separate css file
2. concatenate all css files (including @namespaces separated one at first position) into single css file

Resulting css file will have @namespace directives at the begining of the file following of the content of all the original files.

I am unable compose step 1 where I need to go through the list of provided files (defined in fileset, patternset or included definition) look at the content and pick @namespaces e.g. by some regexp pattern.
Puting found @namespaces into separate file should follow (this should be the easier part of step 1).

Any advices?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might be a suitable starting point.

```
<property name="namespace_file" value="namespaces.css" />
<property name="other_file" value="other.css" />
<property name="all_file" value="all.css" />

<delete>
  <fileset dir="." includes="${namespace_file} ${other_file} ${all_file}" />
</delete>

<concat destfile="${namespace_file}">
  <fileset dir="css_files" includes="*.css" />
  <filterchain>
    <linecontainsregexp>
      <regexp pattern="^@namespace" />
    </linecontainsregexp>
  </filterchain>
</concat>

<concat destfile="${other_file}">
  <fileset dir="css_files" includes="*.css" />
  <filterchain>
    <linecontainsregexp negate="true">
      <regexp pattern="^@namespace" />
    </linecontainsregexp>
  </filterchain>
</concat>

<concat destfile="${all_file}">
  <fileset dir="." includes="${namespace_file} ${other_file}" />
</concat>
```

In this example:

- The source css files are in the `css_files` directory.
- Two work files are created: one for the namespaces, one for the rest of the css.
- Two Ant [`<concat>`](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/concat.html) tasks are used: one to gather the namespaces, one for the rest.
- Each `concat` uses a filterchain with a regular expression.
- A third `concat` joins the collected namespaces to the rest of the css in a single file called `all.css`.